# Laravel: controller not teletransporting me (redirect-ing me) to the page

Tags: laravel-5

from Ajax the controller does get the keyword I want, as it confirms it (because I echo it), and my idea was that on getting that keyword, it should redirect to the page I want. Yet, it does not, and also, while it does change the locale, I have to reload the page, otherwise, it won't show any translation and locale changes on the page. In Firebug when I hover over the POST, I get the correct URL to where I would want to go: sort of http://myweb.com/es but the controller does not change the http URL box of my browser on my web to go there.

I am simplifying the Controller code here, but actually I will want it to go to different URLs depending on the keyword it gets, something that I would do with a switch statement or IF else if etc.

So the controller is as simple as this:

```
public function changelanguage()
    {
        $lang = \Input::get('locale');
        echo "I got $lang";
        Session::put('locale', $lang);
        return redirect('/es');
    }
```

If instead of using ajax I use a Form, then I dont need to reload, the Action of the form makes the controller change the locale and translate the page without reloading. But I need to use ajax and in any case, the controller does get correctly the keyword ('en', 'es', 'de' etc ) for languages, so it should take it from there and redirect me to the URL page, but it just doesnt move.

if you are curious about the Ajax, here it is, but it does send the keyword as I said.

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
            $('.choose-language').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var selectedlanguage = $(this).data('value');
            $.ajax({  // so I want to send it to the controller
            type:"POST",  // via post 
            url: 'language',  
            data:{'locale': selectedlanguage},



            });   // HERE FINISHES THE $.POST STUFF           

        }); //HERE FINISHES THE CLICK FUNCTION       

    }); // HERE FINISHES THE CODE
```

ROUTES

```
Route::post('language', array(

   'as'   =>'language',
   'uses' => 'LanguageController@changelanguage'

));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re trying to perform the redirect in the AJAX-requested script, then it won’t work. You can’t redirect from a script request via AJAX otherwise people would be doing all kinds of nefarious redirects.

Instead, set up a “success” handler on your AJAX request that refreshes your page if the request was successful. It can be as simple as:

```
var url = '/language';
var data = {
  locale: $(this).data('value');
};
var request = $.post(url, data)
  .success(function (response) {
    // Script was successful; reload page
    location.reload();
  });
```

I’m not sure how you’re allowing users to select locales, but since you need a reload any way I think AJAX is pointless here. Just have a traditional form that submits the new locale to an action, set the locale in a session/cookie/whatever, and then redirect back to the referring page.

Comment: Hello, thank you.My point of task is the multilingual site. People select a language from the dropdown menu and you know they work upon a single click. So that would take them to the /en/ or /es/ part of the web for their language.

Comment: I will follow from the lead you indicated, through the success etc, but it will have to go to a different url depending on whether it passed es de it ru etc

Comment: are you then saying actually that I would not even need to contact the controller and change the locales ? i could just on choosing en es de it etc directly to the page section, I would not even need ajax, just an a href tag, but the locale translates the page however, i dont think it spares me any translation work since i have to create the dictionaries at the Lang directories...